# Mocking with Flexmock datetime.datetime.now

Tags: python, datetime, mocking

I am trying to use different tools for mocking and find out the best one. I really like flexmock for its simplicity but I cant figure out how to mock behaving of datetime.datetime.now().

How to mock following behaviour in flexmock?

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> mocker = Mocker()
>>> fake_datetime=mocker.replace(datetime)
>>> fake_datetime.now()
<mocker.Mock object at 0x027F1990>
>>> mocker.result(datetime(year=2012, month=12, day=12))
>>> mocker.replay()
>>> datetime.now()
datetime.datetime(2012, 12, 12, 0, 0)
```

When I try same in flexmock :

```
>>> from datetime import datetime  
>>> fake_datetime = flexmock(datetime)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\virtualenvs\webui\lib\site-packages\flexmock.py", line 1194, in flexmock
    return _create_partial_mock(spec, **kwargs)
  File "C:\virtualenvs\webui\lib\site-packages\flexmock.py", line 1013, in 
_create_partial_mock
if (_attach_flexmock_methods(mock, Mock, obj_or_class) and
  File "C:\virtualenvs\webui\lib\site-packages\flexmock.py", line 1030, in
_attach_flexmock_methods
'Python does not allow you to mock builtin objects or modules. '
    'Python does not allow you to mock builtin objects or modules. '
MockBuiltinError: Python does not allow you to mock builtin objects or modules.
Consider wrapping it in a class you can mock instead
```

or

```
>>>flexmock(datetime).should_receive('datetime.now').and_return(datetime.datetime(2012,12,10))
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'now'
```

Answer (score 4):

Your first approach had the right idea but unfortunately Python does not let you modify builtin objects like datetime.datetime. flexmock monkey-patches the object and hijacks method calls at runtime which is not possible in this case. The error in the exception actually mentions a solution -- you can wrap datetime.datetime in your own class and then mock that. But if you really want to do what Mocker did in your example and just create a fake object with a now() method that returns what you want, you can do that pretty easily:

```
fake_datetime = flexmock(now=lambda: datetime(year=2012, month=12, day=12))
```

But, of course, regular calls to datetime.now() would not be hijacked by flexmock unless you were injecting the fake datetime object into the calling code.

Your second approach produced an error because datetime.should_receive('datetime.now') in flexmock is meant for chained method calls. Which means it expects a call like datetime.datetime().now() rather than datetime.datetime.now() so it ends up complaining about datetime which it expectes to be a function not having method now().